# JavaFX how to disable resizing after a certain stage size

Tags: java, javafx

I just started using Scenebuilder and fxml with JavaFX and I had a quick question. How do I stop the stage from resizing to a smaller size after a certain stage length/width is hit? Heres an image of what I mean: [image]

The background image is really stretched out and it looks really bad, is there a way to prevent the user to resize to a size that makes it stretched out like this? Also, is there a way to instead of resizing the image to fit the window size, a certain part of the image is cut out/zooms in temporarily if the user resizes the window? I think this would make for a really clean effect and it would stop the background of  the app from looking really ugly. Anyways heres the css for my vbox:

```
.bodybg{
 -fx-background-image: url('./Backgrounds/loginimage.png');
 -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Edit: I just want to note that I tried using minWidth and minHeight but those did not work

Edit 2: Here's what I meant by my second question

Here's the login screen for discord:[image: Login Screen]

You can see that the image doesn't look very big, a bit portion of the image is cut off to have that clean affect that makes the background look clean

Now heres the background when I resize it more horizontally
[image]

You can see that the background image got zoomed in. You can't see the mountains like in the background that you were seeing before. This provides the login screen with an extremely good looking affect. This is what I wanted to try to replicate. Anyone know any way to do this?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply removing the `-fx-background-size: 100% 100%;` from the CSS, i.e. you just need to indicate the URL of the image (as you have already done). Then the background image is displayed in its original size and you only see part of it depending on the size of the container that you set the background image for. Note that the top, left corner of the image is aligned with the top, left corner of the container.

I set the background image on the root node of the [scene graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106328). I could not determine, from your question, the node in your scene graph that you are setting the background image for.